# How to remove all comments with CSS Loader with webpack 2 in string mode?

Tags: css, webpack-2, css-loader

I use this config for my webpack 2

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: 'css-loader?minimize'
            })
        }
```

How to remove all comments based on string mode ?
I use this but **does not work**

```
  'css-loader?minimize&{discardComments:{removeAll:true}}'
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin to remove comments: [example](https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/webpack-remove-comments-compressed-css)

Answer (score -2):

Might as well keep going and add SASS in there also. Here is our config.

```
const style_loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  fallback: 'style-loader',
  use: [
    { loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
    { loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: { plugins() { return [Autoprefixer]; } }
    },
    { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
    { loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: { sourceMap: true }
    }
  ]
});
```

Define that above and then below in your rules you can have:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: style_loader
}
```

Then when you add your plugins:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
```

I would import one main.scss file into your whatever .js file is your entry point and then import your _partial.scss files into the main.scss file. That way you can break up your styles and start using all of the sass features also.