# how to remove css comments from css file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am using `nextjs + reactjs` .I want to `remove` all css comments present in my `css` file. For example, a created a simple project for next js. I am using `next-purgecss` to remove unwanted css but still, it is not `removing` comments why?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-jennings-upb7y?file=/next.config.js:73-86
I added a `comment` in my `css` file

```
/*

heloo terr
 */
a {
  background-color: green;
}
```

It should be removed after using `purgecss` plugin.Is there any way to remove these comments

[image]

To run code create a new terminal and run `npm run dev` as it open at `3005` port

[image]

Comment: I checked purgecss documentation but didn't find any info on how it can remove the comments. It just says "PurgeCSS is a tool to remove unused CSS." Maybe it just removes unused classes etc. but not comments

Comment: Maybe answers on this question may help. Even though they are not using purgecss, someone suggested a different plugin for webpack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360631/how-to-remove-all-comments-with-css-loader-with-webpack-2-in-string-mode

Answer (score 0):

Next.js removes comments in CSS automatically. You don't need an extra configuration or CSS processing packages. Run the project in production mode using `npm run build` and `npm start` and comments would be removed from the build.

Generally, in development mode (`next dev`), the build is not optimized for production.

Comment: I checked `npm run build` it not removed the comments

Comment: @user5711656, in your project you're overriding the built-in CSS and SASS loaders with _legacy_ packages `@zeit/next-css` and `@zeit/next-sass`. They are obsolete now and need to be removed. See steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app/60944296#60944296)

Comment: Thanks for answering than how to `add css` file and `remove unwanted css files`

Comment: Actually in my project I have few `scss` and `css` file .In my css file there so my `unused class` are there that why I use `purgecss` plugin .unused `css` is removed but there comments is not removed

Comment: see my example I am using both `scss` and `css` in `_app.js` import "./style.css";
import "../styles.css"; https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-jennings-upb7y?file=/pages/_app.js:85-130 .In `css` file there are some unwanted `css` is present .I want `unused` css will be remove with `comments` .is it possible

Comment: is there any way to removed unused and comments